# Android error when applying material style to alertdialog

Tags: android

This is the styles.xml

```
<resources>


<style name="LottogramTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>

    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/Lottogram.OverflowMenu</item>
    <!--Action bar style-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Lottogram.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Lottogram.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Lottogram.DropdownItem</item>

    <!--<item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>-->
</style>


<style name="Lottogram.DropdownItem" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">@dimen/wrap_content</item>

</style>

<style name="Lottogram.ActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/toolbarHeight</item>
    <item name="height">@dimen/toolbarHeight</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/toolbarHeight</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/toolbarHeight</item>

</style>


<style name="Lottogram.OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-16dp</item>

</style>


<style name="Lottogram.AlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/Lottogram_AlertDialogText</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/Lottogram_AlertDialogTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="Lottogram_AlertDialogText">
    <item name="android:textSize">14.5sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Lottogram_AlertDialogTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

the code

```
//THIS WORKS
      new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this).setTitle("teste").setMessage("In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.").show();

//THIS DOESNT
      new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.Lottogram_AlertDialog).setTitle("teste").setMessage("In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.").show();
```

The manifest application tag has  `android:theme="@style/LottogramTheme"`

The stack trace is

```
Binary XML file line #25 in com.tomatechines.quickbbb:layout/mtrl_alert_dialog: Binary XML file line #38: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #38: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

The error is thrown at the exact line that i commented as doesnt work
just to be 100% clear I HAVE NO LAYOUT NAMED `mtrl_alert_dialog` it is most likely to be a material related stuff

can anyone help me?

Comment: "I HAVE NO LAYOUT NAMED mtrl_alert_dialog it is most likely to be a material related stuff" -- yes, you can find it [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.4.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/res/layout/mtrl_alert_dialog.xml), where I linked to version 1.4.0. What version of the Material Components for Android are you using?

Comment: I found solution any style you set to "materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle" must extends "MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text"